# Remove ending from URLs using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I would like to remove all endings on some URLs that we use on our website. For some reason, lots of URLs get indexed even though they are blocked by robot.txt

Just checked google search console today "Indexed, though blocked by robots.txt" - 1,200+ URLs

they are all in the same form

https://www.ifootpath.com/display-ifootpath-walk?walkID=11470&username

and they should be

https://www.ifootpath.com/display-ifootpath-walk?walkID=11470

the end number will change for each URL (Walking guide) so I guess I would just like to remove '&username'

Thank you

Comment: Usually one wants URLs like `https://www.ifootpath.com/display-ifootpath-walk/11470` for clean search results...

Comment: About google: could it be that those URLs got onto the index _before_ you blocked them inside the robots.txt file?

Comment: Yes https://www.ifootpath.com/display-ifootpath-walk/11470 is the right type of URls which is what we want  - we want to remove the pages with &username from the end. It maybe that they were indexed before the block on robot.txt - but it would be better if they were re-directed (through .htaccess) I belive

Comment: You certainly should redirect them, since those URLs already _are_ in the index according to your description. That means that there will be potential requests to those URLs. You'd need to take care to make an external redirection from those URLs to the pattern you prefer _and_ you need to implement internal rewriting to again resolve that pattern to your internal structure.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the comments to the question you need two steps here:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^walkID=(\d+)&
RewriteRule ^/?display-ifootpath-walk$ /display-ifootpath-walk/%1 [R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?display-ifootpath-walk/(\d+)$ /display-ifootpath-walk?walkID=$1 [END]
```

That rule set will work likewise in the http servers host configuration and in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" style file) inside the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of that host.

Please note that I did not test those lines but only wrote them down as I saw fit. But I do hope I did not make any silly typo or logical mistake...

If you receive a http status 500 ("internal server error") with those rules then chances are that youoperate a very old version of the apache http server. In that case try replacing the `[END]` flag with the `[L]`.

---

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try - much appreciated.